# Volume of the parallelepiped

Tags: determinant, volume

Let vectors $u_1,\ u_2,\ \cdots u_n$ and $\mathcal{P}$ the parallelepiped determined by  these vectors :
$$\mathcal{P}=\left\{\lambda_1 u_1+\cdots +\lambda_nu_n/\ \lambda_k\in [0,1]\right\}$$
How we can prove that :
$$V=\int_{\mathcal{P}}dx_1\cdots dx_n=\det\left(u_1,  u_2, \cdots, u_n\right)$$
Thanks you very much.